# Rails migration: add same column to multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, timestamp, addition

Is there some special syntax to add timestamp column to multiple tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a specific special-purpose syntax, but you can certainly iterate over an array of table names, and perform the same migration steps on each one.

```
class AddTimeStampsToABandC < ActiveRecord::Migration
  AFFECTED_TABLES = [:table_a, :table_b, :table_c]

  def self.up
    AFFECTED_TABLES.each do |t|
      add_timestamps(t)
    end
  end

  def self.down
    AFFECTED_TABLES.each do |t|
      remove_timestamps(t)
    end
  end
end
```